# Can you replace bundle or other assets in an ipa file without rebuilding?

Tags: ios, xcode, build-process

Is it possible to replace bundle or other assets such as png in an ipa file without rebuilding it?

Comment: It's just a compressed file, so I don't why you can't easily try and see for yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Just tried altering an image (`.png`) in the app bundle, it showed with the new background color. I did it in the `.app` folder, not the `.ipa`. It works on the Simulator, but I don't think it would work for Ad-Hoc on device, and maybe not even for a debug build on device (because of code signing).